# Why are these marked as unnecessary imports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Why are these highlighted entries marked as unneccesary imports?

[image: Unnecessary Imports]

I recently added the **Google Contacts** component into my application. I already had the **Google Calendar** implemented.

Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespaces marked as unnecessary is because the aren't used at the specific times it's mentioned.
So you can remove them without any problems, you just have to add them if they are meant to be used.

Comment: OK, thank you for that clarification. It explains it because I have not yet added in any code to work with the contact data. So I will leave the namespaces for now.